# how to animate setting rootViewController for window

Tags: ios

I set rootViewController for window by statement below. However, this statement is not animated.

```
self.appDelegate.window.rootViewController = navController;
```

Is it possible for me to animate this statement with the effect of `NavigationController.popViewController`?

Comment: From which view controller to another view controller?

Comment: Did you set the code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions of appDelegate.m method?

Comment: Do you use storyboard or xib?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I found the answer on another SO thread

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.appDelegate.window
                            duration:.75
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                            animations:^{
                                self.appDelegate.window.rootViewController = navController;
                            }
                            completion:nil];
```

However, it used dissolve effect. If someone could tell me which animation should I use to get the effect of popping from NavigationController.